# WireGuard blocked - apparently a wider UDP issue

Tags: openvpn, blocking, udp, wireguard

WireGuard is refusing to connect, I've tried running it on 2 different VPS providers (with my PC as the client) and it just doesn't work.

There are some commonalities which I noticed:

1. On both servers, OpenVPN works
2. Neither server accepts UDP packets from Angry IP scanner or Nmap

I know for a fact that this is not a WireGuard block by my ISP, because WireGuard works on NordVPN and PIA. I also know that the server providers aren't at fault, because the WireGuard connection establishes for my friend using a different ISP.

My question is, why does OpenVPN work on 1194 UDP, but WireGuard, Nmap & AngryIP all fail?

Nmap results:

1194/udp    open|filtered   openvpn

51820/udp   open|filtered   unknown

I really don't even know where to start with diagnosing this problem, so I apologize if the information I've provided is insufficient.

Comment: 1) Are you saying that the server doesn't show any received UDP packets even on `tcpdump`, or have you not tested that yet? 2) Does the server become able to receive packets if it initiates the stream first (e.g. if you ping a WG client from the server)? 3) What happens if you use 1194 as the WireGuard port?

Comment: Yup, it's not that it's being "denied" by the server, per se. There is literally no trace of UDP packets sent by Nmap to my server.

I'm able to ping WG clients as long as they're connected.

I've tried that as well, yes. I've tried a plethora of port to no avail.